# I want to render the data format of my choice dynamically in REST api

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have to render the data format of my choice at run time.

E.x.

```
public class Message {



@Id 
private String version;

private String title;

private String content;

private String sender;

private String url;
}
```

now if i hit the url http://localhost:8080/messages/12345/xml it should return xml  format
and if i hit the url http://localhost:8080/messages/12345/json then i should return json format

but the end point should be same
http://localhost:8080/messages/12345

I am very new to Spring boot and REST ,it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, for json you don't need a converter or libraries spring boot have jackson library so it will automatically converts your pojo into json. For xml response add jackson-dataformat-xml dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

and while returning response convert pojo to xml response like this

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setVersion();
// set all the values if you want otherwise take the message object and pass
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
```

This will return xml response